# There is something like pip+virtualenv for php?

Tags: php, virtualenv, package-managers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does php have an equivalent to python’s virtualenv or ruby’s sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182176/does-php-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-virtualenv-or-rubys-sandbox)

Exist some tool like virtualenv and pip for php?